# How to populate value when trying to create record from quick create

Tags: lightning, opportunity, lookup

I have a custom object (XYZ__c) lookup on Opportunity. When I am creating an Opportunity, I can create a new XYZ__c record from quick create on the Opportunity page layout.

There is an Account lookup on XYZ__c object. While creating an XYZ__c record can I pre-populate account value on XYZ__c record taking the account value from Opportunity.

Is there any way pre populate values from quick createw

Ex -

When u have a lookup field on a standard page in lighting, when u put cursor on the field, it will ask u search or create a new record. When u click on the create new record + sign, a page opens .. I want to pre populate some of the fields in there

Regards

Comment: There is no standard way to achieve what you want. You have to go custom and build a Lightning web component or aura component.